# OneDrive for Business - Critical Error when trying to sync files

Tags: windows, windows-8, onedrive, sharepoint, mapped-drive

I've been getting a critical error recently with OneDrive when it attempts to synchronize:

[image: OneDrive critical error]

I use the OneDrive component mainly to sync with SharePoint files, so this has become very annoying. This started happening recently after I mapped a network drive to a remote server, but I cannot verify that this is actually the cause, and I have since disconnected that mapped drive. I've gone through multiple steps in an attempt to remedy this.

- I've run the OneDrive troubleshooter, but repairing/troubleshooting it yieled no success or useful information. (http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/onedrive-troubleshooter)
- I've removed all cached credentials following the instructions in this post by a MSFT Support employee, but the error still persisted. (http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/148/t/263688.aspx#806298)
- I've tried following the steps here from a MSFT Support employee, which basically removes a bunch of cached files that may be causing the issue, but this didn't fix the issue. (http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/154/t/236194.aspx#734728)
- I've tried restarting the service, restarting the computer, etc. The issue also happens at my workplace network, and at home, so it's not network related.

Any ideas?

*Windows 8.1 Pro, 64bit*

Comment: Anything in the event logs?

Comment: @DavidPostill, surprisingly enough, no; no events that I could find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After installing the latest Windows updates, my error went away. I installed all three important updates listed.

[image]